# How to remove namespace in XML through java?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, marshalling

using XSD file I have generated JAXB classes and finally doing marshalling through these JAXB classes to generate XML file. But output is coming like this:-

```
 <Central_Case_Id xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/xmls_schema-instance"/>
```

Expected output for each should element in XML should be like this:-
[code=java][/code]

I did lot of search on internet, I changed   xsd property, elementFormDefault to "unqualified" and also added attributeFormDefault property to both qualified and unqualified but nothing works.

XSD:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="ICMS" targetNamespace="ICMS"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Case_Detail" minOccurs="0"/>
       </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Case_Detail">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Central_Case_ID"/>
        <xs:element ref="Agency_Case_ID"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Central_Case_ID" nillable="true">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Agency_Case_ID" nillable="true">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```

Expected Output for each element is:-

```
<Central_Case_Id></Central_Case_Id>
```

Can you please suggest me what properties in XSD file or in marshalling will help me in achieving this? My requirement is to have none of element in XML should contain any namespace/attributes even if it is blank or null values.

Thanks

Comment: This is the 3rd time you have asked this same question.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your XSD you have nillable="true". Remove this from your XSD regenerate the JAXBElements and then check the output.